# Probleme with batch - script

Tags: css, algorithm, batch-file

i have 1000 photos with extension `.jpg` and every name of photo is a code like this `12345.jpg`.

And i have 1000 folders with names like this: `text_text_text_code(000000)`

the job is put every photo in every single folder, i can solve this, but not working very well.

I found the problem, but i don't know how to solve.

in name folder i have `text_text_text_code(000000)`, i need the code to stop when it arrives at character `(`.

```
@echo off
chcp 1250
echo.
echo.
cd "C:\Users\folderexample\Desktop\123"
for /r "C:\Users\folderexample\Desktop\imagem" %%a in (*.jpg) do (
    for /f %%b in ('dir /b *"%%~na"*') do copy "%%a" "%%~fb"
)
```

I would like the search to go to the character `(` and go to next search up until finish photos.

Comment: So you want to match the code of the file `12345.jpg` with the code of the folder, before the parenthesis? text_text_text_code` or the code inside the parenthesis?

Comment: Additionally `echo.` is more reliable as `echo(` Rather use `cd /d` in case your script initiates from another drive.

Comment: Please clarify what portion you are looking to match as stated in my first comment in order for someone to assist as currently the question is unclear.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1 delims=(" %%b in...` (were you could omit `tokens=1`, as it's the default anyway)

Comment: Gerhard first option. Before the parenthesis.

Comment: Stephan so how i can use the script?

Comment: not working with "tokens" :/